# how to create a GCP Load Balancing with whitelist backend host ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, amazon-elb, gcp-load-balancer

I want to create a load balancer with my whitelisted on-premise machines behind it, this way I can check-in and check-out my external backend host ip address.

I've looked at several load balancers and backend services configuration but can't seem to figure it out.

The main idea is for my backend hosts to service my requests, taking in consideration that they are not instances located within GCP. I'm looking for a GCP lb that can help me forward traffic outside this cloud.

Comment: Howdy ... I think I'm hearing you say you want to create a load balancer exposed to the Internet.  Where I'm getting lose on the question is what you mean by whitelisting the machines behind it.  What does it mean to check-in/check-out and IP address?   You say youve been looking at some configurations.  What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: so  I have some backend hosts can service my requests. but they are not gcp instances. I want a GCP lb can help me arrange my request traffic to these list of backend hosts.

Comment: It feels like what you might want to review is this article and see if it helps:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-external-backend-internet-neg